# can not add compute method

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12, computed-field

the issue is simple, I just need to create a computed field. here is what I have:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.model'

    a = fields.Float()
    b = fields.Float()
    value = fields.Float(compute='_compute_value')

    @api.depends('a','b')
    def _compute_value(self):
        for record in self:
            record.value = a/b
```

but when I want to check it from the web browser on the db, I see that it's not added to compute

[image]

(calculer in french stands for compute which is empty)

what can be the issue?

Comment: You computed field is worked only when a and b field is change.I think you even don't add a and b value.

Comment: The calculation (method) is also called when the computed field is "shown" in a view.

Comment: Your code example looks fine. So maybe your "real" code has a mistake? Can you add the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create `my.model` fields, Odoo will execute the following query:

```sql
INSERT INTO ir_model_fields (model_id,model,name,field_description,help,ttype,state,relation,index,store,copied,on_delete,related,readonly,required,selectable,size,translate,relation_field,relation_table,column1,column2,track_visibility) 
VALUES 
(390, 'my.model', 'a', 'A', NULL, 'float', 'base', NULL, false, true, true, NULL, NULL, false, false, true, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(390, 'my.model', 'b', 'B', NULL, 'float', 'base', NULL, false, true, true, NULL, NULL, false, false, true, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(390, 'my.model', 'value', 'Value', NULL, 'float', 'base', NULL, false, false, false, NULL, NULL, true, false, false, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(390, 'my.model', 'id', 'ID', NULL, 'integer', 'base', NULL, false, true, true, NULL, NULL, true, false, true, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(390, 'my.model', 'display_name', 'Display Name', NULL, 'char', 'base', NULL, false, false, false, NULL, NULL, true, false, false, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(390, 'my.model', 'create_uid', 'Created by', NULL, 'many2one', 'base', 'res.users', false, true, true, 'set null', NULL, true, false, true, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(390, 'my.model', 'create_date', 'Created on', NULL, 'datetime', 'base', NULL, false, true, true, NULL, NULL, true, false, true, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(390, 'my.model', 'write_uid', 'Last Updated by', NULL, 'many2one', 'base', 'res.users', false, true, true, 'set null', NULL, true, false, true, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(390, 'my.model', 'write_date', 'Last Updated on', NULL, 'datetime', 'base', NULL, false, true, true, NULL, NULL, true, false, true, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(390, 'my.model', '__last_update', 'Last Modified on', NULL, 'datetime', 'base', NULL, false, false, false, NULL, NULL, true, false, false, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) RETURNING id
```

You can see that `compute` is not present in the column names. Its value is not stored in database

Comment: thanks for the info, well you did answered the question, but mainly my problem is that I am on a migration from saas to sh, and for that field I had some code in `compute`, so I tried to override it with python code, but it doesn't change (I have allways the old code in `compute`). so I tried to delete the model and recreate it, and compute was empty (so I posted this question)